# For a regression model, can you transform all your features to linear to make a better prediction?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, linear, feature-engineering

I was thinking. Would it be a good approach to check your features one by one (assuming you have a manageable amount of them) and see the relationship they have with your target variable, if they have a non linear relationship then transform each of those features using their appropriate function for each case to make them linear? In my mind if you do this your are guaranteed to have a better Linear model and also you are able to perform hypothesis testing on each feature to see the relevance of them, giving you the chance to perform some feature selection as well.

I know that the interpretability of model will be thrown out of the window, but the model will give a much better performance. Basically you could potentially end up with a model with only engineer features (assuming that all of them have a non linear relationship)

Would this approach be acceptable and it is worth exploring?

Comment: Assuming that the features are independent, you can work on each feature one by one and explore the link with the dependent variable, then transform them and put all the transformed feature together in a regression. If the dependencies between features is high, then clearly when you analyze the relationship between each non-linear feature and the dependent variable, you are missing the effect of the other left-outside features, which may make your analysis less reliable depending on the degree of interaction between them. But if it is mild, I think it may be numerically acceptable anyway